# delegation vs aggregation vs consultation

Tags: language-agnostic, concept

What is the difference between these terms, can you give please small examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_pattern

> In Design Patterns, an aggregate is
>   not a design pattern but rather refers
>   to an object such as a list, vector,
>   or generator which provides an
>   interface for creating iterators.

Meaning in short on elements contains 0 or more other elements of another type.

```
public class MyAggregation 
{   
   protected List<MyAggregates> aggregates = new List<MyAggregates>();

   public void add( MyAggregate element )
   {
        aggregates.Add( element );    
   }
}
```

Delegate: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

> In software engineering, the
>   delegation pattern is a design pattern
>   in object-oriented programming where
>   an object, instead of performing one
>   of its stated tasks, delegates that
>   task to an associated helper object

Meaning that some class uses another object to do something.

```
public interface IExceptionHandler
{
    void handle( string filename );
}

public class FileDeleteExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
   public void handle( string filename )
   {
      File.Remove( filename );
   }
}


public class MyExceptionHandler
{
    protected IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    public MyExceptionHandler( IExceptionHandler theHandler )
    {
       this.exceptionHandler = theHandler;
    }

    public void handleException( string filename )
    {
       excpetionHandler.handle( filename );
    }
}
```

Or in C# delegation can just refer to a delegate function, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/900fyy8e%28VS.80%29.aspx

Consultation I know nothing off, sorry

hth

Mario

Note: I did not actually compile the code above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a description of the difference between delegation and consultation [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DelegationAndConsultation).

It would seem that what most folks refer to as delegation might more properly be referred to consultation.

I guess that delegation in the more formal sense described in the reference would be implemented as an Abstract base class delegating to a Concrete class.